# What's the right way to export a DXF file in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, export

I have exported a DXF file from Mathematica and I am trying to import it in AutoCAD.

The file that has been exported is output of a command like the following

```
g = Graph[vl, edges, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {v_ :> ({x[v], y[v]} /. solution)}, 
 EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
 EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", .3]}, VertexSize -> .7, 
 VertexStyle -> Red]
```

More details can be found in my previous post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220334/scaling-the-edge-length-of-a-graph-to-be-equal-to-edge-weight)

The following graph was exported from Mathematica using the command : `Export["file.dxf", Show[Graph3D[g]]]`
 [image]

The file obtained after export is shared [here](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/test7_scaled.dxf).

But when I try to open the file in AutoCAD, the drawing window in AutoCAD shuts.

Could someone look into this?

If this doesn't work, can I export in other formats?

EDIT: The solution suggested below doesn't work when the output is obtained as a result of the following command

```
g3d = Graph3D[vl, edges, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {v_ :> ({x[v], y[v], z[v]} /. solution3d)}, 
  EdgeWeight -> ew, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  EdgeLabels -> {e_ :> Placed["EdgeWeight", .5]}, VertexSize -> .3, 
  VertexStyle -> Red, ImageSize -> Large]
```

I  think the problem here is solution3d already as x,y,z coordinates in it.
When I export the output to dxf using

```
Export["file.dxf", Show[Graph3D[g3d]]]
```

the exported dxf can't be imported in AutoCAD.

Answer (score 2):

The DXF file you made isn't wrong, but it's in a different format than your original. Your original DXF was a set of lines in 3D. Here's how to make a simple DXF file from the answer's solution. Refer to the answer at [Scaling the edge length of a graph to be equal to edge weight](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/220576/41569).

1) The `solution` from the answer has new 2D vertex coordinates. Get line data from the original DXF file.

```
solution = {x[1] -> 74.8765323341147, y[1] -> 38.338839560418336, 
  x[2] -> 123.40647961090141, y[2] -> 47.8708899668093, 
  x[3] -> 8.917284888177424, y[3] -> 2.766361654099819, 
  x[4] -> 45.00000011321871, y[4] -> 0.,
  x[5] -> 97.09834751979837, y[5] -> 73.57592753317832,
  x[6] -> 49.91286233087924, y[6] -> 60.18973414245018,
  x[7] -> 0., y[7] -> 24.999999734296512, 
  x[8] -> 13.634582696340212, y[8] -> 59.0724623077659, 
  x[9] -> 114.99999830823879, y[9] -> 24.99999745723544};
ld = Import["input.dxf","LineData"]
```

> ```
> {{1,2}, {1,3}, {1,4}, {2,5}, {2,6}, {5,6}, {3,4}, {3,7}, {6,7}, {7,8}, {2,9}}
> ```

2) Change the 2D vertices from the `solution` to 3D by setting the `z` coordinate to zero. Create lines from the line data, `ld`, and the vertex coordinates, `vd`.

```
vd = Append[#, 0.] & /@ Partition[Values[solution], 2];
lines = Line[vd[[#]]] & /@ ld;
```

3) Make a 3D graphic of the lines and export to a DXF file.

```
g = Graphics3D[lines, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Top]
```

[image: lines displayed in 3D graphic]

```
Export["output.dxf", g];
```

Comment: I could import the file into AutoCAD . Thanks a ton. Could you please let me know if it is possible to  retain the edge labels and vertex labels in the dxf export?

Comment: Yes, you can find how from [Labeling a three-dimensional plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33239/41569). For the vertex labels, check how `order` is used to place the numbers in the correct order. Instead of `pos[[i]]`, `vd[[i]]` are the vertex coordinates.

Comment: Could you please explain why `g = Graphics3D[lines, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Top, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]` doesn't work?

Comment: And if I were to use this, `labels = Table[Inset[Style["Label " <> ToString[i], Bold, 20], vd[[i]]], {i, Length@holes}];` what should go in place of holes?

Comment: Edge lengths are obtained like this, `edgeLengths = # -> 
     Norm[Through[{x, y}@First[#]] - Through[{x, y}@Last[#]]] /. 
    solution & /@ EdgeList[g3d]`. Please suggest how this has to be addd to `g`. `solution` and `g3d` are from answer provided from previous post

Comment: Please have a look at my edit

Comment: `VextexLabels` doesn't work because `Graphics3D` does not have that feature, see `Options[Graphics3D]`.  Your graph has 9 vertices, so change `Length@holes` to `Length@vd`. It's much easier to get the edge lengths from `ArcLength/@lines`.